# Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿A que corresponde el siguiente error?:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Este es mi código:

```
import math

print("teoria de inventarios")
print("elige el modelo")
print("1.-modelo deterministico")
print("2.-modelo con rebastecimiento instantaneo en un periodo de tiempo ")
print("3.-modelo de lote economico de producion")
print("4.-modelo probabilistico")
while (True):
    opcion=input(">")

    if (opcion=="1"):
        Q=0
        print("ingrese K")
        K=input()
        print("ingrese D")
        D=input()
        #print("ingrese T")
        #T=input()
        #print("ingrese P")
        #P=input()
        print("ingrese H")
        H=input()
        Q=2*K*D/H**1/2
        print(Q)

    elif(opcion=="2"):
        Q=0      
        print("ingrese K")
        K=input()
        print("ingrese D")
        D=input()
        #print("ingrese T")
        #T=input()
        print("ingrese P")
        P=input()
        print("ingrese H")
        H=input()
        Q=2*K*D/H
        raiz=math.sqrt(Q)
        print(Q)

    elif(opcion=="3"):
        print(" opcion 3")
    elif(opcion=="4"):
        print(" opcion 4")
    else:
        print("opcion invalida")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la función input retorna un string, por ejemplo lo puede comprobar imprimiendo el tipo:

```
valor = input()
print(type(valor))
```

Esto retorna lo siguiente:

```
<class 'str'>
```

La solucion sencilla es convertir el string a float o int, es decir reemplazar:

```
valor = input()
```

por:

```
valor = float(input())
```

---

## Opcional:

Ademas de ello me di el tiempo de comprimir tu código para que se pueda configurar facilmente como muestro a continuación:

```
import math

print("teoria de inventarios")
print("elige el modelo")
print("1.-modelo deterministico")
print("2.-modelo con rebastecimiento instantaneo en un periodo de tiempo ")
print("3.-modelo de lote economico de producion")
print("4.-modelo probabilistico")


data = {"1": (["K", "D", "H"], lambda K, D, H:  2*K*D/H**1/2 ),
         "2": (["K", "D", "P", "H"], lambda K, D, P, H: math.sqrt(2*K*D/H))}

while True:
    opcion = input(">")
    if opcion in data.keys():
        variables, fun = data[opcion]
        args = []
        for variable in variables:
            print("ingrese {}".format(variable))
            valor = float(input())
            args.append(valor)
        resultado = fun(*args)
        print(resultado)
    else:
        print("opcion invalida")
```

## Uso:

Si deseas añadir más opciones debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Añadir la opción.
2. Una lista de los nombres de las variables que se deben pedir.
3. un funcion lambda indicando la formula.

Por ejemplo:

Digamos que queremos usar la siguiente formula asociada a la opción `"3"`:

```
a**2 + b*p
```

Entonces debes de tener lo siguiente:

- opcion: `"3"`
- lista de variables: `["a", "b", "p"]`
- función: `lambda a, b, p:  a**2 + b*p`

Obteniendo lo siguiente:

```
data = {"1": (["K", "D", "H"], lambda K, D, H:  2*K*D/H**1/2 ),
         "2": (["K", "D", "P", "H"], lambda K, D, P, H: math.sqrt(2*K*D/H)),
         "3": (["a", "b", "p"], lambda a, b, p:  a**2 + b*p)}
```

Comment: y como meterias mas formulas a los metodos? por que esos valores son el valor de q  y nesesito q para otras formulas

Comment: @FranciscoAczayacatlGarciaGo He colocado un ejemplo.

Comment: @FranciscoAczayacatlGarciaGo Puedes usar la solucion simple de reemplazar `input()` por `float(input())`, la otra solucion es opcional y he asumido muchas cosas ya que no has dado mas informacion.

Comment: eso si lo entiendo pero por ejemplo en el metodo numero uno tiene otras formulas que seria Q/D  que Q es el resultado de 2*K*D/H**1/2

Comment: Si tus estructuras correctamente lo que quieres el modelo se podria ampliar y darte una solucion, pero por ahora te recomiendo solo hacer el cambio de `input()` a `float(input())`

Comment: pero en el ejemplo que me enseñaste tiene float(input()) a cual ejemplo me estas diciendo que cambie eso, al mio o al tuyo?

Comment: En tu codigo solo has ese cambio

Comment: gracias ya funciono

Comment: @FranciscoAczayacatlGarciaGo Si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta.